# Action is assigned type "of never" when it's surely should not

Tags: typescript, redux

Disclaimer: I'm using electron boilerplate from https://github.com/iRath96/electron-react-typescript-boilerplate

It has some nice actions creators code there (copy paste from boilerplate for better context:)

```
import { Action } from 'redux'

export interface IAction extends Action {}
export interface IActionWithPayload<T> extends IAction {
  readonly payload: T
}

interface IActionCreator<T> {
  readonly type: string
  (payload: T): IActionWithPayload<T>

  test(action: IAction): action is IActionWithPayload<T>
}

interface IActionCreatorVoid {
  readonly type: string
  (): IAction

  test(action: IAction): action is IAction
}

export const actionCreator = <T>(type: string): IActionCreator<T> =>
  Object.assign((payload: T): IActionWithPayload<T> => ({ type, payload }), {
    type,
    test(action: IAction): action is IActionWithPayload<T> {
      return action.type === type
    },
  })

export const actionCreatorVoid = (type: string): IActionCreatorVoid =>
  Object.assign((): IAction => ({ type }), {
    type,
    test(action: IAction): action is IAction {
      return action.type === type
    },
  })
```

So, to create new actions I simply do:

```
export const fetchAllBackgroundsPending = actionCreatorVoid('FETCH_BACKGROUNDS_PENDING')
export const fetchAllBackgroundsSuccess = actionCreator<IBackground[]>('FETCH_BACKGROUNDS_SUCCESS')
export const fetchAllBackgroundsRejected = actionCreator<IAPIError>('FETCH_BACKGROUNDS_REJECTED')
```

And it works just perfectly: my `action.payload` is now typed.

However, if I use more than 2 branches in my reducer, I get type of "never" on my payload:

```
const backgroundsReducer = (
  state: IBackgroundsState = initialState,
  action: IAction
): IBackgroundsState => {
  if (fetchAllBackgroundsPending.test(action)) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isCollectionLoading: true,
    }
  }

  if (fetchAllBackgroundsSuccess.test(action)) {
    return {
      ...state,
      // action has a type of never!
      byId: mergeById(state, action.payload)
    }
  }

  return state
}
```

As far as I can tell from the docs, TS is hinting me that the code branch will never run, but that's not the case: if I put `console.log` there I can observer them! So, it looks like TS is making a mistake... or I do?

I understand that the code provided here doesn't look like minimal example, so if it's not clear enough, please let me know and I'll try to come up with an minimal repo illustrating this issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAllBackgroundsPending.test` is declared as a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
test(action: IAction): action is IAction
```

That is, you are telling TypeScript to assume that `test` returns true *if and only if* the argument is of type `IAction`.  Since the `action` parameter to `backgroundsReducer` is of type `IAction`, if `fetchAllBackgroundsPending.test(action)` returns false (indicating that `action` is not an `IAction`), then there is no possible type remaining for `action`, so it gets type `never`.

I believe what you really want for `test` is a "one-sided" type guard, which [TypeScript does not yet support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048).  But in this case, it should be fine to just change the return type of `test` in `IActionCreatorVoid` to a plain `boolean` (making `test` no longer a user-defined type guard at all), since the "true" case was not determining a more specific type for the action anyway.  I'd encourage you to file an issue against the boilerplate project you used.

While the `test` method of `IActionCreator` in principle should also be one-sided, the current declaration isn't likely to cause problems because when you test a variable of type `IAction`, the "false" case just leaves the variable as `IAction`; TypeScript currently doesn't have a way to express exclusion of `IActionWithPayload<T>` from `IAction`.

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood how type guards work! I thought that TS would analyze what JS function will return (in this case it is possible) and based on that, assigned whether A is B or not. Though, the problem with returning just `boolean` instead of  type guard results in having just `IAction`, which has no `payload`. Whether in theory I can cast that to my type manually I'd like to avoid that... I thought that I was doing something wrong since I used popular boilerplate, hence was the question :D Thank you so much. I'll go with `typesafe-actions` lib then :D